# C++ Find maximum element of an array USING ONLY POINTERS

Tags: c++, loops, pointers, for-loop

I have an assignment where I have to find the max and min element of an array using only pointers. The directions say you have to use pointers for everything but didn't make it clear if you can make variables then just not use them and make pointers pointing to them or if there literally cant be one regular variable declaration in the program.

I already did the whole assignment by declaring variables then making pointers point to them but just to be safe I'm redoing it with no variables.

The only thing I'm having trouble with is making a for loop with only pointers because there is no variable set to 0 that I can make a pointer point to and get the memory address of 0 to start the counter.

I would just do this:

```
int i = 0;

int *counterptr = &i;

cout << "Please input the array values" << endl;

for (*counterptr ; *counterptr < 10; *counterptr += 1)
{

}
```

But since I cant make variable i to point to I don't know how to get the memory address of 0 to use for the pointer. This is what I have right now but I don't know what to make `counterptr` equal to.

```
float nums[10];
int *counterptr = ;
float *maxptr, *minptr, *difference;
maxptr = &nums[0];
minptr = &nums[0];

cout << "Please input the array values" << endl;

for (*counterptr ; *counterptr < 10; *counterptr += 1)
{
    cin >> nums[*counterptr];
    if (nums[*counterptr] > *maxptr)
    {
        maxptr = &nums[*counterptr];
    }
    if (nums[*counterptr] < *minptr)
    {
        minptr = &nums[*counterptr];
    }

}
```

Any help would be appreciated thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

corrected program snippet given below. It can be written better, but I modified for your understanding from your code changed to work now. counterptr is a pointer within the array elements (as an iterator), *counterptr will be one of the elements, similarly *minptr and *maxptr are minimum and maximum elements whereas, minptr and maxptr are respective pointers to minimum and maximum elements within the array of floating point numbers. Hope this helps.

```
float nums[10];
float *counterptr;
float *maxptr, *minptr, *difference;
maxptr = &nums[0];
minptr = &nums[0];

cout << "Please input the array values" << endl;

for (counterptr = nums, counterptr < nums + 10; counterptr++)
{
    cin >> *counterptr;
    if (*counterptr > *maxptr)
    {
        maxptr = counterptr;
    }
    if (*counterptr < *minptr)
    {
        minptr = counterptr;
    }

}
```

Comment: thank you this works perfectly but I dont understand why it works. If you have time can you explain it a little more. When you set counterptr = nums which value of nums does it actually set it to(becuase its an array it has 10 different values and you didnt put an index). Also why didnt you set counterptr = &nums to get the memory address of it so that it doesnt change the value of nums on accident when you do counterptr++ in the for loop?

Comment: @BenjaminDagg nums is equivalent to &num[0] and counterptr is just traversing through the list as a pointer, initially pointing to the first element and then when incremented, points to the second and so on. Hope this clarifies.